# Add correlation ID to all logs in Azure Function logger

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, dependency-injection, azure-functions

All my Azure Functions are HttpTrigger. And the callers add a "correlation-id" header to the all requests.

I know I have access to the request from any custom service class with IHttpContextAccessor injected in the constructor. I would like to avoid to use IHttpContextAccessor from all my custom service classes.

For instance:

logger.LogInformation($"{correlationId}: Saving some entity to DB");

// "7eec51f0-4046-4398-b044-45ecf905cd81: Saving some entity to DB"

It would be better:

customLogger.LogInformation("Saving some entity to DB");

// "7eec51f0-4046-4398-b044-45ecf905cd81: Saving some entity to DB"

I tried to create a custom logger provider and a custom logger from examples here:

https://github.com/elmahio/Elmah.Io.Extensions.Logging/blob/main/samples/Elmah.Io.Extensions.Logging.Function/Startup.cs

But the problem seems to be trying to use the default .NET ILogger<> from my custom Logger. Which I guess it makes sense.

Has anyone tried to solve this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this CustomLogger which works. change the Msg when telemetryclient send it to application insights.
1.Create .net6 isolated function template in visual studio, install package `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore`

// Reach the headers using "FunctionContextAccessor" (https://gist.github.com/dolphinspired/796d26ebe1237b78ee04a3bff0620ea0 )
2. Copy code from above link to create `FunctionContextAccessor.cs` `IFunctionContextAccessor.cs` `FunctionContextAccessorMiddleware.cs`

3.`CustomLogger.cs`

```
    public class CustomLogger : ILogger
    {
        private readonly IFunctionContextAccessor _functionContextAccessor;
        private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

        public CustomLogger(IFunctionContextAccessor functionContextAccessor, TelemetryClient telemetryClient )
        {
            this._functionContextAccessor = functionContextAccessor;
            this._telemetryClient = telemetryClient;

        }

        public IDisposable? BeginScope<TState>(TState state) where TState : notnull
        {
            return default!;

        }
        
        public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Log<TState>(
            LogLevel logLevel,
            EventId eventId,
            TState state,
            Exception exception,
            Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter
        )
        {
           
            var correlationId = string.Empty;
            if (_functionContextAccessor.FunctionContext != null)
            {
                var context = _functionContextAccessor.FunctionContext.GetHttpRequestDataAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
              
                correlationId = context.Headers.GetValues("correlationId").FirstOrDefault();
            }

            string Msg = formatter(state, exception);  //get the real Msg from 
            Msg= correlationId+ ": " + Msg;

            TraceTelemetry traceTelemetry = new TraceTelemetry(Msg, GetSeverityLevel(logLevel));
            _telemetryClient.TrackTrace(traceTelemetry);

        }

        private static SeverityLevel GetSeverityLevel(LogLevel logLevel)
        {
            return logLevel switch
            {
                LogLevel.Critical => SeverityLevel.Critical,
                LogLevel.Error => SeverityLevel.Error,
                LogLevel.Warning => SeverityLevel.Warning,
                LogLevel.Information => SeverityLevel.Information,
                _ => SeverityLevel.Verbose,
            };
        }

    }
```

4.`program.cs`

```
var builder = new HostBuilder();
builder.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(app=>{
    app.UseMiddleware<FunctionContextAccessorMiddleware>();
});

builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddSingleton<CustomLogger>();
    services.AddSingleton<IFunctionContextAccessor, FunctionContextAccessor>();

    var config = new TelemetryConfiguration() { ConnectionString= "InstrumentationKey=xxx;IngestionEndpoint=xxx;LiveEndpoint=xxx" };
    services.AddSingleton<TelemetryClient>(new TelemetryClient(config));
});
var host = builder.Build();
host.Run();
```

5.Function1.cs

```
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly CustomLogger _logger;   //You could also use services.AddSingleton<ILogger, CustomLogger>();
        public Function1(CustomLogger logger)
        {
            this._logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("Test accessing headers");


            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

            return response;
        }
    }
```

Test Result

[image]